# program that finds results of two digits python

Tags: python, user-input

Write a program that finds two digit A and B (dont search the web,
and dont try 'manually') so that we get a two digit number AB (say
A = 8, B = 9 then the number is 89) and so that AB*AB = CAB for
some digit C. Thus if you square AB you get a 3 digit number. The
two last digits in AB^2 are AB but the first digit is some C that may
not related necessarily to A or B.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to do your own homework... any programmer worth his salt will immediately recognize the wording as a homework problem :-)

Comment: dont search the web, and dont try 'manually', dont raise question on stackoverflow, they should add

Comment: Look, we're a friendly bunch, we'll happily _help_ people with their homework, _when they show they've tried and got stuck_. This isn't even trying. Is this for a math class, and you're supposed to _think_ about the numbers? Or is this for a programming class, and you're supposed to write a brute-force algorithm to search through all 89 possibilities to find the right answer?

Comment: i dont have a problem with really writing the program I am just not quite understanding the way the exercise is worded. It is clear to that the AB example is presented wrong in someway which i was thrown off by. But written more clear I would understand.

Comment: How about: x^2 - x = c where 10 <= x < 100 and c = 100 * k for some positive integer k < 10. Solve for x.

Comment: What's really interesting is that when you find AB, and compute CAB, then you'll find that CAB*CAB = FDECAB - how cool is that!

Comment: @Gabby - you had A=9 and B=8 giving AB as 89, this is backwards (I've edited for you). Is this what was confusing you?  (Of course, A=9,B=8 does not give the correct solution, its just an example.)

Answer (score 2):

In pseudo-code, you could simply do something like:

```
def findAB (c):
    c = c multiplied by 100
    for a in 0..9: # or possibly 1..9
        for b in 0..9:
            set ab to a multiplied by 10 plus b
            if (ab multiplied by ab) is equal to (c plus ab):
                return (a,b)
    return nothing
```

My preferred language for pseudo-code is close enough to Python that it shouldn't be *too* hard to convert but your first step should be understanding how it works. To that end you should run the code in your head, filling out a variable sheet like:

```
  c  |  a  |  b  |  ab  |  return
-----+-----+-----+------+----------
     |     |     |      |
     |     |     |      |
     |     |     |      |
     |     |     |      |
```

The sooner you start thinking like a machine, the better a programmer you'll become - just make sure you don't boot out all those social skills though, they'll still come in handy at certain points in your life :-)

Answer (score 2):

Simply, in code:

```
for a in range(1,10):
   for b in range(10):
       ab = a*10+b
       ab2 = ab*ab
       if (ab2 % 100) == ab:
           print "a=",a,", b = ",b
```

Comment: I hope he doesn't want the absolute value of anything here.  Maybe rename `abs` to `ab2`.

Comment: Thanks @Paul McGuire, I agree! I have amended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to brute force, take two minutes and think about the problem. Think about A - what is the smallest number A could be? What is the largest?  Think about B - there is something special about B, some special property that only 4 of the total 10 digits have. In the end, you will still have to loop over a couple of sets of numbers for A and B, but if you use only the set of likely numbers, you will show that you have put some intelligent thought into your solution.  And as I said before, this problem generalizes to some interesting larger cases, for instance, you can find a number ABCDEF which, when squared gives ######ABCDEF.

Bonus: do you think there is a largest possible number that has this property?